# Parsing Google calendar to DDay.iCal

Tags: c#, google-api, deserialization, icalendar, dday

I'm working on application which parses Google Calendar via Google API to [DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/)

The main attributes, properties are handled *easily*... ev.Summary = evt.Title.Text;

The problem is when I got an **recurring** event, the XML contains a field like:

```
<gd:recurrence>
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20100916
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20100917
    RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
</gd:recurrence>
```

or

```
<gd:recurrence>
  DTSTART:20100915T220000Z
  DTEND:20100916T220000Z
  RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=9;WKST=SU"
</gd:recurrence>
```

using the following code:

```
    String[] lines = 
evt.Recurrence.Value.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    foreach (String line in lines)
                    {

                        if (line.StartsWith("R"))
                        {
                            RecurrencePattern rp = new RecurrencePattern(line);
                            ev.RecurrenceRules.Add(rp);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            ISerializationContext ctx = new SerializationContext();
                            ISerializerFactory factory = new DDay.iCal.Serialization.iCalendar.SerializerFactory();

                            ICalendarProperty property = new CalendarProperty();

                            IStringSerializer serializer = factory.Build(property.GetType(), ctx) as IStringSerializer;

                            property = (ICalendarProperty)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(line));

                            ev.Properties.Add(property);
                            Console.Out.WriteLine(property.Name + " - " + property.Value);
                        }

                    }
```

RRULEs are parsed correctly, but the problem is that other property (datetimes) values are empty...

Comment: Did you mean to use colons after DTSTART and DTEND in your first example? And is there meant to be a double quote after SU in the second example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the starting point of what I'm doing, going off of [the RFC-5545 spec's recurrence rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-37). It isn't complete to the spec and may break given certain input, but it should get you going. I think this should all be doable using RegEx, and something as heavy as a recursive decent parser would be overkill.

`RRULE:(?:FREQ=(DAILY|WEEKLY|SECONDLY|MINUTELY|HOURLY|DAILY|WEEKLY|MONTHLY|YEARLY);)?(?:COUNT=([0-9]+);)?(?:INTERVAL=([0-9]+);)?(?:BYDAY=([A-Z,]+);)?(?:UNTIL=([0-9]+);)?`

I am  building this up using http://regexstorm.net/tester.

The test input I'm using is:

> DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20140711T133000\nDTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20140711T163000\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=8;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20141101
>
> DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20140711T133000\nDTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20140711T163000\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=5;INTERVAL=8;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20141101
>
> DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20140711T133000\nDTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20140711T163000\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20141101

Sample matching results would look like:

```
Index    Position    Matched String                                                 $1      $2  $3  $4  $5
0        90          RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=8;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20141101           WEEKLY      8   FR  20141101
1        236         RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=5;INTERVAL=8;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20141101   WEEKLY  5   8   FR  20141101
2        390         RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR;UNTIL=20141101                      WEEKLY          FR  20141101
```

Usage is like:

```
string freqPattern = @"RRULE:(?:FREQ=(DAILY|WEEKLY|SECONDLY|MINUTELY|HOURLY|DAILY|WEEKLY|MONTHLY|YEARLY);?)?(?:COUNT=([0-9]+);?)?(?:INTERVAL=([0-9]+);?)?(?:BYDAY=([A-Z,]+);?)?(?:UNTIL=([0-9]+);?)?";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(rule, freqPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    string frequency = m.Groups[1].ToString();
    string count = m.Groups[2].ToString();
    string interval = m.Groups[3].ToString();
    string byday = m.Groups[4].ToString();
    string until = m.Groups[5].ToString();
    System.Console.WriteLine("recurrence => frequency: \"{0}\", count: \"{1}\", interval: \"{2}\", byday: \"{3}\", until: \"{4}\"", frequency, count, interval, byday, until);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a great example of when to use regular expressions. Try this out for general parsing:

```
\s*(\w+):((\w+=\w+;)+(\w+=\w+)?|\w+)
```

Or, you might decide to have something more schema-specific.

```
\s*(?:DTSTART:)(?'Start'\w+)
\s*(?:DTEND:)(?'End'\w+)
\s*(?:RRULE:)(?'Rule'(\w+=\w+;)+(\w+=\w+)?)
```